# KeystoneJS 6 - graphQLSchemaExtension - No session

Tags: typescript, session, graphql, schema, keystonejs

I have an issue with `graphQLSchemaExtension`

I don’t have active **session** on my custom mutations..

An example below of the beginning of custom mutation
And my graphQLSchemaExtension declaration
And my `Keystone.ts` file

On my generic **queries/mutations** on playground I have a **session**.
On my frontend too

Thanks <3

[image: resolvers/mutations/confirmBooking.ts]

[image: resolvers/index.ts]

[image: Keystone.ts]

I tried to change secure option on keystone.ts but nothing change
Check on google, check on KeystoneJS github issues

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you say "I don’t have active session on my custom mutations" you mean that, in your custom mutation resolver, the `session` property of the `context` argument is coming though as `null`?

Not sure what's causing this in your case. I've created a simple Keystone app with session and a custom mutation but failed to reproduce the issue you describe. In the current release of Keystone the custom GraphQL syntax is a bit different that the version you're on ([docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/schema-extension), [examples](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/extend-graphql-schema-graphql-ts)). It's also possible whatever problem you were seeing has been fixed. Hard to know without knowing the specific version you have in your `package.json`.

My example has just a User list that can be authenticated and a mutation called `getRandom` that returns a random float. The entire thing is ~50 lines; here's the `keystone.ts`:

```
import { list, config, graphql } from '@keystone-6/core';
import { statelessSessions } from '@keystone-6/core/session';
import { allowAll } from '@keystone-6/core/access';
import { text, password } from '@keystone-6/core/fields';
import { createAuth } from '@keystone-6/auth';
import { Context } from '.keystone/types';

let sessionSecret = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10).repeat(4);
let sessionMaxAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

const { withAuth } = createAuth({
  listKey: 'User',
  identityField: 'email',
  secretField: 'password',
  sessionData: 'name',
});

const lists = {
  User: list({
    access: allowAll,
    fields: {
      name: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),
      email: text({ isIndexed: 'unique', validation: { isRequired: true } }),
      password: password(),
    },
  }),
};

const extendGraphqlSchema = graphql.extend(base => ({
  mutation: {
    getRandom: graphql.field({
      type: graphql.Float,
      args: {},
      resolve(source, {}, context: Context) {
        console.log('Dumping session object:', context.session);
        return Math.random();
      },
    }),
  },
}));

export default withAuth(
  config({
    db: {
      provider: 'postgresql',
      url: process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://molomby@localhost/ks6-auth',
    },
    lists,
    session: statelessSessions({
      maxAge: sessionMaxAge,
      secret: sessionSecret,
    }),
    extendGraphqlSchema,
  })
);
```

I'm running this out of the examples directory in a clone of the main Keystone repo so package versions are current, specifically: `@keystone-6/auth@5.0.1` and `@keystone-6/core@3.1.2`.

The DB was manually seeded with a single user so I could authenticate:
[image: user record in the DB]

Then I start the app and hit the custom mutation:

```
mutation {
   getRandom
}
```

If there's no current session, then `context.session` is null, as you'd expect:

```
Dumping session object: undefined
```

But if I sign into the Admin UI using the seeded user record, then hit the mutation from the GraphQL Playground (in the same browser, of course), I get my GraphQL resolver dumps the session object you'd expect:

```
Dumping session object: {
  listKey: 'User',
  itemId: 'claro2yq40008lh6y5wpkh2s1',
  data: [Object: null prototype] { name: 'Molomby' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response

Yes `context.session` is null on custom mutation

I don't understand the new syntax for GraphQL Extension as :

```
const extendGraphqlSchema = graphql.extend(base => ({
  mutation: {
    getRandom: graphql.field({
      type: graphql.Float,
      args: {},
      resolve(source, {}, context: Context) {
        console.log('Dumping session object:', context.session);
        return Math.random();
      },
    }),
  },
}));
```

What's the `type` for ? ( graphql.float)

My extensions :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@keystone-6/auth": "^4.0.0",
    "@keystone-6/core": "^2.1.0",
    "@keystone-6/fields-document": "^4.0.1",
    "@keystonejs/server-side-graphql-client": "^2.1.2",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "next": "12.2.4",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.2",
    "stripe": "^8.161.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
```

**The better solution is to share this repo. It's an open-source project to learn**

Project link : https://github.com/thibault60000/keystone-6-backend

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: The `type` in for the custom mutation is the GraphQL return type. I've added links to my answer for the docs and some examples. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I will try this new syntax. Thanks

Comment: Hi

I tried to use https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/schema-extension#title with 'Using Third-Party Tools'  | 'GraphQL-Tools Merge Schemas' syntax

I have another anwser

Answer (score 0):

With 'Graphql Tool Merge Schemas' from documentation (https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/schema-extension#title)

'context.session' continue to be undefined :/

```
export const extendGraphqlSchema = (schema: GraphQLSchema) =>
  mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [schema],
    typeDefs: `
      type Query {
        allGifts: [Gift]
      }
      type Mutation {
        confirmBooking(giftId: ID!): Boolean
      }
    `,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        // Testing
        allGifts: (root, { id, days }, context: Context) =>
          context.db.Gift.findMany(),
      },
      Mutation: {
        // To implement
        confirmBooking: (root, { giftId }, context: Context) => {
          console.log('CONTEXT', Object.keys(context));
          /*
            'db',           'query',
            'totalResults', 'prisma',
            'graphql',      'maxTotalResults',
            'sudo',         'exitSudo',
            'withSession',  'req',
            'session',      'startSession',
            'endSession',   'gqlNames',
            'images',       'files'
          */
          const session = context.session as Session;
          console.log('SESSION', session); // undefined
          return true;
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: Rather than posting answers, that just extend the question, please choose to edit the question or making a comment if it is as a reaction to someones answer

Comment: Are you sure the HTTP call that hits the `confirmBooking` mutation does in fact carry the cookies that identify an existing session? Obviously, if these are missing, the request will be processed without the session object being populated.

Comment: Hello
Sorry for the double answer. I am not a regular user of StackOverflow.
That's my problem. I don't understand why the mutation doesn't contain a cookie in the context. Normally it should exist. I am well connected on the frontend, and the Keystone admin.
Maybe a configuration problem... I don't know and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

With 'Graphql Tool Merge Schemas' from documentation (https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/schema-extension#title)

'context.session' continue to be undefined :/

```
export const extendGraphqlSchema = (schema: GraphQLSchema) =>
  mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [schema],
    typeDefs: `
      type Query {
        allGifts: [Gift]
      }
      type Mutation {
        confirmBooking(giftId: ID!): Boolean
      }
    `,
    resolvers: {
      Query: {
        // Testing
        allGifts: (root, { id, days }, context: Context) =>
          context.db.Gift.findMany(),
      },
      Mutation: {
        // To implement
        confirmBooking: (root, { giftId }, context: Context) => {
          console.log('CONTEXT', Object.keys(context));
          /*
            'db',           'query',
            'totalResults', 'prisma',
            'graphql',      'maxTotalResults',
            'sudo',         'exitSudo',
            'withSession',  'req',
            'session',      'startSession',
            'endSession',   'gqlNames',
            'images',       'files'
          */
          const session = context.session as Session;
          console.log('SESSION', session); // undefined
          return true;
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

I tried to use your `graphql.extend(base)` syntax
And the log `dumping session object` is undefined too :)

```
export const extendGraphqlSchema = graphql.extend((base) => ({
  mutation: {
    confirmBooking: graphql.field({
      type: graphql.Float,
      args: {},
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty-pattern
      resolve(source, {}, context: Context) {
        console.log('Dumping session object:', context.session);
        return Math.random();
      },
    }),
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem - spent hours combing the web & keystone docs for any info on why it might be happened and found nothing, but then realised that auth headers were not being passed as I was calling the mutation from the graphql sandbox api explorer.

Long story short - if you have set it up like the keystone 6 docs, your logged in frontend should be able to call the mutations no problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).